# default select option in multiple select option

Tags: php, html

is that possible create default select in multiple select options but that default select not selected.

like default notification, when we not select anything will displaying "Nothing Selected".

[image: Default Notification]

i want to change that "Nothing Selected" for example with "Select Category"

my code

```
<select multiple class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="nama_kat" name="nama_kat[]" form="tambahposting">
   <?php foreach ($data2 as $value): ?>
   <div class="form-group">
      <option>
         <?php echo $value['nama_kat'] ?>
      </option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please share your code.. it will helps you to get quick answer.

Comment: sorry, added...

Comment: whay are you using `<div class="form-group">` in select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your result with this example.

You have to add attribute `selected` which option you want to select by default.

You have to put `if` condition when you have some value exact match with option value than you can select option by default.

**Example**

> `<option value="notification_default" <?php if( $i == 'notification_default'): echo 'selected="selected"'; endif; ?>>Default Notification</option>`

You can add this in your option.

```html
<select multiple class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="nama_kat" name="nama_kat[]" form="tambahposting">
      <option value="1">test 1</option>
      <option value="2">test 2</option>
      <option value="3" selected="selected">default notification</option>
      <option value="4">test 4</option>
      <option value="5">test 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that defaul selected will selected http://i.imgur.com/yJQJGQv.jpg, i want default selected but not selected, just for notification...